# How to change the URL email is coming from

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

How to change the "FROM URL" to my "website name"? I tried to change it via

```
System -> Configuration -> Store Email Addresses
```

and Transactional Email, but there is nothing which can change that.

Comment: am not talking about changing the template, rather i want to change the "URL" emails are recieved from.

Comment: or adding a second line to it which should state my business name or website name ?

Comment: is there anyone who could help me out ??? or atleast rank this question so that it comes in the eyes of someone who may the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by following these three steps:

1. Make changes to php.ini on line #683

   `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fname@Domain.net -nMY CompanyName`
2. Changed lib/Zend/mail.php line #686

   `$this->_storeHeader('From', 'name@Domain.net', true);`
3. In cPanel created email account with the same name "name@Domain.net"

Answer (score 0):

This is a php mail setting, deep in the innards of the machine. Do you own the box or are you on shared hosting? Maybe make this question more generic and consider trying another app, e.g. Wordpress, to see if it is hosting or Magento.

Comment: hosting server is BlueHost and they gave me this link to follow on but its still not helping
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/000206

Comment: Have you tried setting Magento to use `sendmail`? It is an option in admin.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System -> Configuration -> Contacts
so, you can set 'Send Emails To' field